# Return nested array key name instead of index

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to return the name and value by looping through an array and for that I'm using the `array_walk_recursive` function. All works fine, except that it's returning the nested array indexes instead of the name. In the example below I want the indexes to be 'name3' but as the main array is dynamic, the loop can't be specific for that nested array.

Array

```
   Array
(
    [name1] => value
    [name2] => value
    [name3] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
        )

)
```

Function

```
function test($value, $name) {
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='$name' value='$value'>";
}
array_walk_recursive($array, 'test');
```

Output

```
<input type='hidden' name='name1' value='value'>
<input type='hidden' name='name2' value='value'>
<input type='hidden' name='0' value='value1'>
<input type='hidden' name='1' value='value2'>
```

Comment: That function can't use the key. You need to write an own recursive function to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than i thought, a nested foreach is needed for that.

```
foreach ($array as $name => $value) {
  if (is_array($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $name2 => $value2) { 
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$name."[]".'" 
         value="'.$value2.'">';
    } 
  } else {
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$value.'">';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this

```
foreach ($array as $name => $value) {
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        // convert it to string by the way you want
    }
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='$name' value='$value'>";
}
```